# Unable to load url as its showing connection error using requests module

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to scrape ajio.com but encountered connection error. Can someone help me out on this.

This was my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
men_jacket= []
url="https://www.ajio.com/"
page= requests.get(url)

And this is the error: ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection you are trying to make has been closed by the server, this may be due to high network traffic or maybe you are in denial of service because of too  many requests by the script. You should check the **robots.txt** before scraping. So far to my knowledge you can wait until the server whitelists you.

Answer (score 0):

As it identify request from machine and it get blocks so you can give `user-agent` as header in `get` method you can find it in Network Tab under chrome developer mode where find headers of URL

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
men_jacket= []

headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36"}

url="https://www.ajio.com/"
page= requests.get(url,headers=headers)
page.status_code
```

Output:
`200`

```
bs(page.text,"html.parser")
```